# How can I make Heroku interact with files on my github repo?

Tags: python, file, github, heroku, bots

I'm trying to host a python bot on Heroku, however I get an error when on the line that requires to open a file:

```
2020-11-18T17:52:14.845145+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-18T17:52:14.845173+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "bot/checkcomment.py", line 16, in <module>
2020-11-18T17:52:14.845272+00:00 app[worker.1]:     with open("../csv/pro.csv", "r") as pro:
2020-11-18T17:52:14.845309+00:00 app[worker.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../csv/pro.csv'
```

Using the URL of the file in the repo didn't work either. What should I do?
I also need the bot to save a file in the repo, if possible.

Comment: I think you'll ned to host your repo on Heroku (that's what I did), but I'm not 100% sure if you can't use github

Comment: That worked. Thanks.